# Change how often new wireless networks are scanned for

Tags: wireless

I am looking for a way to modify how often Ubuntu will look for new wireless networks available.

I do not mind if it is modifying a file, issuing a command, or with a GUI or any other way.

I am NOT looking for a way to scan for new wireless networks, but to modify how often ubuntu does it automatically.

Ubuntu 18.10.
Details of my wireless card:

```
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak]
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 10
   serial: 18:1d:ea:6a:51:b2
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.18.0-13-generic firmware=29.1044073957.0 ip=192.168.43.129 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:128 memory:df000000-df001fff
```

Comment: I assume you are using Network Manager.  That is a **hardcoded** value - to change it you would need to recompile all the Network Manager components.  It'd be a pain in the butt to do.  (I filed a feature request in Network Manager to be able to configure the scanning rate but that was a couple years ago and I haven't gotten a reply)-